# Why do I get two random slope terms when forcing no correlation between random slope and intercept in lme4?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am running a mixed effects logistic regression using lme4 in R.

I have one predictor that is a dichotomous categorical variable. It is coded 1/0 and is defined as a factor.

I find that the random item intercept is perfectly correlated with the random item slope for my predictor. So, I run a new model in which they are uncorrelated using the following code:

```
m1<-glmer(DV~1+PPTGender+(1|Subject)+(1+PPTGender||Item), data = data, family = "binomial")
```

However, the output gives me two terms for the random slope:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: DV ~ 1 + PPTGender + (1 | Subject) + (1 + PPTGender ||      Item)
   Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   499.7    526.9   -242.9    485.7      353 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7334 -1.0057  0.6312  0.8807  1.3858 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name              Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr 
 Subject      (Intercept)       6.323e-10 2.514e-05      
 Item         (Intercept)       2.785e-09 5.278e-05      
 Item.1       PPTGender0        5.229e-01 7.231e-01      
              PPTGender1        6.889e-03 8.300e-02 -1.00
Number of obs: 360, groups:  Subject, 60; Item, 36

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     0.28229    0.17833   1.583    0.113
PPTGender -0.07718    0.29534  -0.261    0.794

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
PPTGndr     -0.635
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

If I redefine the PPTGender variable as a numeric character variable like so:

```
data$PPTGender<-as.numeric(as.character(data$PPTGender))
```

It goes away:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: DV ~ 1 + PPTGender + (1 | Subject) + (1 + PPTGender ||      Item)
   Data: data

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   500.8    520.2   -245.4    490.8      355 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4075 -1.0489  0.7410  0.8472  1.1603 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name          Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Subject      (Intercept)   3.638e-10 1.907e-05
 PairNumber   (Intercept)   2.081e-01 4.562e-01
 PairNumber.1 PPTGender     1.091e-08 1.044e-04
Number of obs: 360, groups:  Subject, 60; Item, 36

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    0.26056    0.14625   1.782   0.0748 .
PPTGender     -0.03009    0.26720  -0.113   0.9103  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
PPTGendr    -0.397
```

Is this just a quirk in R? Is there anything wrong with this latter approach?

Comment: You need a numeric variable, otherwise the parameter is not a "slope".

Comment: Can you explain why that is? I seem to get the same results with factors and numeric variables in every case EXCEPT with the random intercept and slope for that variable are uncorrelated.